# Ubuntu 12.04: cannot install apache2-common

Tags: installation, apt, apache2

I've just upgraded to 12.04 from 10.04, and upgraded apache2. I ran into the following:

- While trying to install passenger, it complained that `apache2-prefork-dev` was missing.
- `sudo apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev` complains:

  `apache2-prefork-dev : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) but it is not going to be installed`
- `sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common` complains:

  `apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) but it is not going to be installed`
- `sudo apt-get install apache2.2-bin` installs.
- `sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common` still does not find it.

I've uninstalled all of apache several times, purged, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: I should add I've searched high and low, and not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried a fresh 12.04 LTS install. The key issue is I've added the `ppa:ondrej/php5` repo for php 5.4. This includes apache 2.4 without development headers. As a result I have Apache 2.4.6 installed, but when I go to install development headers the package index only finds it for 2.2.

If I am to stay with 12.04, it appears I can only get results by compiling from scratch.

If I want managed packages for php 5.4 and apache 2.4, I cannot stay with 12.04 LTS.

Note that everything would be fine if I only needed normal PHP and static pages. I need to install Phusion Passenger for Rails also, so 12.04 is not an option.

I will try upgrading to 13.10 and comment here again.

Comment: After upgrading to 13.10 apt-get found all dependencies.